# Issue with pillow saving files with the wrong file extension

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

My code doesn't seem to work, it shows no errors but it doesn't work correctly. it's supposed to save the images with the file extension chosen but it just saves it with no file extension.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import rembg
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import font
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green


root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title("Bulk")
root.geometry('410x280')
myFont = font.Font()
resize = IntVar()
ratio = IntVar()
white_bg = IntVar()
format = StringVar()

def OnResizeCheck():
    if resize.get() == 0:
        resize_entry_w.delete(0, END)
        resize_entry_h.delete(0, END)
        ratio_box_choice.configure(state='disabled')
        ratio_text.configure(state='disabled')
        resize_text.configure(state='disabled')
        resize_entry_w.configure(state='disabled')
        resize_entry_h.configure(state='disabled')
        ratio_box_choice.deselect()

    else:
        ratio_box_choice.configure(state='normal')
        ratio_text.configure(state='normal')
        resize_text.configure(state='normal')
        resize_entry_w.configure(state='normal')
        resize_entry_h.configure(state='normal')



def OnRatioCheck():
    if ratio.get() == 0:
        resize_entry_h.configure(state='normal')

    else:
        resize_entry_h.delete(0, END)
        resize_entry_h.configure(state='disabled')



def Browse_func(is_input):
    global images
    if is_input:
        images = fd.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Select The Images",
                                filetypes=[("png, jpg, jpeg", "*.png"), ("png, jpg, jpeg", "*.jpg"),
                                           ("png, jpg, jpeg", "*.jpeg")])
        Browse_entry.configure(state="normal")
        Browse_entry.delete(0, END)
        Browse_entry.insert(0, str(len(images)) + " image(s) selected")
        Browse_entry.configure(state="readonly")


    else:
        global output_dir
        output_dir = fd.askdirectory(initialdir="/", title="Select Output Folder")
        Save_to_entry.configure(state="normal")
        Save_to_entry.insert(0, output_dir)
        Save_to_entry.configure(state="readonly")

def process():
    global output_dir
    for image in enumerate(images):
        print(image[1])
        new_image = Image.open(image[1])
        if resize == 1:
            if ratio == 0:
                new_image = image[1].resize(resize_entry_w.get(), resize_entry_h.get())
            else:
                w, h = new_image.size
                ratio = h / w
                new_h = int(ratio * resize_entry_w.get())
                new_image = new_image.resize((resize_entry_w.get(), new_h))
                new_image.save('pic.png')
        if rotate_entry != '0':
            new_image.rotate(int(rotate_entry.get()))
        if white_bg == 1:
            new_image = rembg.remove(new_image)
            white_image = Image.new("RGBA", new_image.size, "WHITE")
            white_image.paste(new_image, (0, 0), new_image)
        new_output_dir = output_dir + f'\{image[0]}'
        if format == 'png':
            new_image.save(new_output_dir, 'PNG')
        else:
            new_image.convert('RGB').save(new_output_dir, "JPEG")
        img_percent = (100/(len(images) + 1))/100
        progress_bar.set(progress_bar.get() + img_percent)

    proceed_button.configure(state='normal')







def Proceed():
    progress_bar.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=5)
    proceed_button.configure(state='disabled')
    process()


#defining and adding widgets

Select_images_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Select Images")
Browse_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="", width=10, command=lambda: Browse_func(True))
Browse_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, state="readonly", width=190)

Save_to_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Save to")
Save_to_Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="", width=10, command=lambda: Browse_func(False))
Save_to_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, state="readonly", width=190)
resize_text_choice = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Resize")
resize_box_choice = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(root, text=None, variable=resize, command=OnResizeCheck)
ratio_box_choice = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(root, text=None, variable=ratio, command=OnRatioCheck)
resize_box_choice.select()
ratio_box_choice.select()
ratio_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Keep ratio")
resize_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Resize res")
resize_entry_w = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, width=65)
resize_entry_h = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, width=65, state="readonly")

rotate_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Rotation angle")
rotate_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, width=65)
rotate_entry.insert(0, '0')

whitebg_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="White bg")
whitebg_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(root, variable=white_bg, text=None)

format_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Format")
format_drop = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(root, variable=format, values=["jpg", "png"], width=65)
format_drop.set("jpg")

proceed_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text='proceed', command=Proceed)
progress_bar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(root, orientation=HORIZONTAL, mode='determinate', width=250)
progress_bar.set(0)

Select_images_text.grid(row=0, column=0)
Browse_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3, sticky='w')
Browse_entry.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

Save_to_text.grid(row=1, column=0)
Save_to_Button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=3, sticky='w')
Save_to_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, pady= 3, sticky='w')

resize_text_choice.grid(row=2, column=0)
resize_box_choice.grid(row=2, column=1, padx= 4)
ratio_text.grid(row=3,column=0)
ratio_box_choice.grid(row=3, column=1,pady=3)
resize_text.grid(row=4, column=0)
resize_entry_w.grid(row=4, column=2)
resize_entry_h.grid(row=4, column=3)

rotate_text.grid(row=5, column=0)
rotate_entry.grid(row=5, column=2)

whitebg_text.grid(row=6, column=0)
whitebg_switch.grid(row=6, column=1)

format_text.grid(row=7, column=0)
format_drop.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky='w')

proceed_button.grid(row=8, column=3, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

This just saves the files with no extension.
I want it to actually save the files with an extension.
I tried almost everything I can think of but still can't figure it out, if someone can help me that would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share minimal example, what shows your problem.

Comment: Please make sure your code is [mcve]. If it's about **PIL**, we don't need to see any `tkinter`, buttons or boxes. Use [edit] button.

Comment: When you save you need to give the whole file name, including an extension.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. Can you reduce the example down to a [mcve]? It seems like the issue is just in calling `new_image.save`, and that function doesn't care where its inputs come from.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are attempting to save based on the index of the selected files in the images list returned and then naming it on that index and adding the extension.
The problem is you have to define the extension in the string/path.

One way is:

```
image.save("output.jpg")
```

Another way is:

```
save("output.jpg", format="JPEG")
```

The 2nd method in this case is exactly the same as the 1st but the reason we have the option to provide a format is to explicitly decide how to encode the file. In the first example it assumes JPEG format based the extension. But in both cases we must provide the extension. You however are not providing this.

Your paths end in the index of the selected images so something like this:

```
C:/Users/test/Videos\0
C:/Users/test/Videos\1
```

To fix this change line:

```
new_output_dir = output_dir + f'\{image[0]}'
```

To this:

```
new_output_dir = output_dir + f'\{image[0]}.{format.get()}'
```

Really you should use f string for the entire path for cleanliness IMO.

Something like this:

```
new_output_dir = f'{output_dir}\{image[0]}.{format.get()}'
```

As you can see from the below image my 2 selected test images saved fine with extension after making that change.

[image]

There are a few things you can do to clean up your code but for now this should correct your file save issue.